# Manipulating with GridView visually in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am new in ASP.NET (C#), I tried to manipulate with GridView control, I bound it with Data Source graphically (as in the image NOT manually) with MS Visual Studio 2010 and projected some data in this GridView graphically as well. I would like to know where I can find the auto-generated code (C# and SQL) of all what I have done?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A dynamic data website generates pages at runtime and it is not some auto generated code by Visual Studio.
A brief about it could be found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/377291/An-Introduction-to-ASP-NET-Dynamic-Data-from-a-Beg

Comment: I know that fact about dynamic website and it is by no matter with my question. I am asking about the code that MS VS will generate when I do my development `Visually` by (drag, drop, insert ...etc.) there must be a generated code in the background of IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I i correctrly understand - you work with WinForms and add some elemets to youк form, now you want to see auto-generated code for added elements on form

Just expand tree with your form and select file NAME.Designer.cs

Maybe [this Post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fb70b63d-1a5b-4b1c-b9d0-f7d4110cea27/where-to-find-autogenerated-code-for-c-windows-forms?forum=csharpide) or [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786512/changing-autogenerated-code-in-a-c-sharp-windows-forms-application-project/3787374#3787374) can be helpfull for you

[image]

Comment: No! I am not talking about winform absolutely.